# NaN error message in field transferring text radio button values to another field

Tags: javascript, forms

My objective is to accumulate results of a multi-page questionnaire form into a summary page. Specifically I wish to take the selection from radio buttons and check boxes and place their values into another field on the summary page. This works fine when the radio button selections are numbers. I use the following script in the calculation pane (Custom calculation script) of the destination field of the summary page e.g.

```
var v1 = +getField("Hx.LBPWorst").value;
event.value=v1
```

The variable `Hx.LBPWorst` is a radio button with 11 buttons, 0-10 and the selected option is transferred to another field on the summary page without problems
My problem is that I wish to transfer text choices rather than numbers from a radio button E.g.
The radio button `Hx.mech.prosit` has four options “Worse”, “Better”, “NE”, “Varies”. The destination field for the selected option is a field with the format set to “None”. I have attempted to use the same structure i.e.

```
var v2 = +getField("Hx.mech.prosit").value;
event.value=v2
```

In this case the destination variable is filled with `NaN` i.e. Not a Number. I have read some of the questions and answers in this forum and apparently the problem is that radio buttons actually don’t store the selection as text. How can I achieve my objective and still use radio buttons (or check boxes)?

Answer (score 0):

Change `+getField` to `getField`

```
var v2 = getField("Hx.mech.prosit").value;
```

The [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) is changing the string to a number. When it can not convert it to a number, you get the NaN.

Comment: I have tested you answer and it solves the problem. Thank you very much. Much appreciated. Mark BOP